# Reference to a definition of a graph homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, graph-theory, homology, graph-minors

Let $G$ be a graph, and define $C_k$ to be the free abelian group on the homomorphisms from graphs $H$ such that $K_k$ is a minor of $H$ without needing to do any vertex deletions, only edge contractions. We can think of such an $H$ as having an identification of the vertices of $H$ with the vertices of $K_k$ such that all the vertices identified with $i$th vertex of $K_k$ form a connected subgraph of $H$ and there is an edge between subgraph identified with $i$ and the subgraph identified with $j$ for $i \neq j$. We can then define a map $\delta_k$ from $C_k$ to $C_{k - 1}$ by sending a homomorphism $\varphi: H \rightarrow G$ to the $\sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{ i + 1} \varphi|_{1 \dots i - 1, i + 1, \dots k}$ where $\varphi|_{1 \dots i - 1, i + 1, \dots k}$ represents a homomorphism from $H$ minus the subgraph identified with $i$ to $G$, which as such a graph has $K_{k - 1}$ a minor without needing to do any vertex deletions, is an element of $C_{k - 1}$ (we also reorder the vertices in the standard way.  Furthermore,  $\delta_{k - 1} \circ \delta_{k}$ is the zero map, so we see this forms a complex. Thus, we have a homology.

I tried to find any references to this particular definition of a homology, but was only able to find references to singular and simplicial homology. I find this particular definition interesting, as it seems like if we have a nice enough homomorphism $\psi$ from $G \rightarrow F$, and information about the homology of $F$, we can pull back the information about $F$ to say something about $G$. In particular, if $F$ is a complete graph and $\psi$ induces a surjective homomorphism from $H_n(G)$ onto $H_n(F)$, we should be able to say something about the kinds of minors $G$ has.

I would appreciate it if someone has any references to this homology, but understand if none are available.

Comment: Nice question. Two questions so I understand: (i) Are the first few sentence right? I'm confused by what $K_k$ is and are the maps from $H$ to $G$? etc etc (ii) Are your graphs all the one-skeleton of some simplicial complex or simplicial set? If so maybe those simplicial/singular references are enough, and if not can you share why?

Comment: (i) $K_k$ is the complete graph on $k$ vertices, that is its vertex set is the numbers from $1$ up to $k$,  and $i$ is adjacent to $j$ for all $i \neq j $.  Then, we look at graphs $H$ that can be partitioned into $k$ parts so that each part induces a complete subgraph and there are edges between these parts. We then take the graph theoretic homomorphisms from such a $H$ to $G$, i.e. maps $f$ on the $V(H)$ such that if $xy$ is an edge in $H$, then $f(x)f(y)$ is an edge in $G$.

Comment: (ii) If we look at the edge, the second singular homology is zero, but I have a proof that the second minor homology is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, we know for sure they’re distinct.